# Simple Excel vlookup doesn't work

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am a programmer that rarely uses Excel. I'm now trying to do a simple vlookup and it just won't work. I have read several online tutorials and troubleshooting guides, no dice. Here's what I've got:

[image]

As you can see, the formula in B8 is `=VLOOKUP(A8,$A$1:$B$5,1,FALSE)`

I am baffled why this isn't working. I have absolutely verified that each cell in the lookup table (A1-B5) doesn't contain any leading/trailing spaces, no special chars, etc. In fact I typed these in manually, they're not pasted. Same goes for the little column of colors (A8-A11). This is the simplest case possible. For example, I want the formula in B8 to look at "Red" in A8, find Red in the lookup table, and return Red's number, which is "3". And I want an exact match.

In case you're wondering why I'm trying this on a simple and useless case, it's because I began on a more complex sheet, as part of prepping for a data import from Excel, got the #N/A everywhere, so I started a new worksheet and made this simple example, and got the same wrong result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the look up value should be in the left hand column?

Comment: You're right, I found that right after I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better served by using [`index()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/index-function-HP010342608.aspx) and [`match()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx) because in a `vlookup()`, the value that you're trying to look for has to be in the left-most column.

`match()` will return the number or index (in your case, the the row number) in which it finds the value you're looking for, and that can be given to `index()` to use to return some other value associated with that index (in this case, the color number in that row).  It would end up looking like this:

```
=index($a$1:$a$5, match(a8, $b$1:$b$5, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the lookup value (color) must be in the left column and the ID must be in the right column.

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP doesn't work to it's left, this function looks rightwards. This is why you need to swap numbers and colors.